# Why do linear (OLS) models often outperform other predictive models?

Tags: multiple-regression, predictive-models, least-squares, linear-model, data-mining

Recently, I've tested many prediction models on real datasets (collected by myself). But most datasets that I collected perform best using an OLS MLR hypothesis compared to many other machine learning/data mining models, and after spending spending a lot of time on preprocessing or data transformation. I found that OLS still work best in most cases, even for datasets that do not follow the OLS assumptions.

I feel frustrated that things don't work as the textbook told me.

My question is:
  Is it just me, or do many others have the same experience?

Comment: How large are the datasets you are trying to model; Why do you assume non-linear relationships to be present? A linear model is very powerful because it only estimates an intercept and slope(s). If data are limited, this might result in better predictions than a complicated model with more parameters than can be accurately estimated from the data.

Comment: Least-squares as an optimization technique does not have any assumptions (beside that the solution must be computable).

Comment: Frans Rodenburg: You're right. Not a large dataset, it's about 20 thousand samples and 107 attributes, I assume it is nonlinear based on my domain knowledge.  What I think is that algorithms like svm or boosting regression, It may not perform better than MLR, but as least their performance will  equal as MLR fitted by OLS. 

Michael M :  It's my bad,  What I mean is estimators would be bias, because some attributes are highly correlated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20'000 lines and around 100 columns is comfortably large to be outside the small sample settings (100 observations or so) where e.g. gradient boosting does not do well. A well tuned gradient boosting tree (a science for itself...) will outperform a linear model by quite some degree, even if most relationships are linear. The reason for this is that even if you invest ages, you cannot guarantee to capture that one key interaction between $\log(X_1)$, $X_2^3$ and $\sqrt X_3$...

Since I don't have access to your data, I will drop some R code with the diamonds data set of `ggplot2`. Maybe you can adapt it slightly to fit your data set. In your situation, with many strongly correlated predictors, I'd assume that elastic-net regression will beat a pure OLS. Since the code for optimizing the gradient boosting model via cross-validation is relatively long and uninteresting, I did not put it here.

```
#======================================================================
# Regression Examples using Diamonds data
#======================================================================

library(glmnet)
library(ggplot2) # for data set "diamonds"
library(xgboost)
library(ranger)


#======================================================================
# Data prep 
#======================================================================

diamonds <- transform(as.data.frame(diamonds),
                      log_price = log(price),
                      log_carat = log(carat),
                      cut = as.numeric(cut),
                      color = as.numeric(color),
                      clarity = as.numeric(clarity))

# Train/test split
set.seed(3928272)
.in <- sample(c(FALSE, TRUE), nrow(diamonds), replace = TRUE, p = c(0.15, 0.85))

x <- c("log_carat", "cut", "color", "clarity", "depth", "table")

train <- list(y = diamonds$log_price[.in],
              X = as.matrix(diamonds[.in, x]))
test <- list(y = diamonds$log_price[!.in],
             X = as.matrix(diamonds[!.in, x]))

trainDF <- diamonds[.in, ]
testDF <- diamonds[!.in, ]

#======================================================================
# Small function
#======================================================================

rmse <- function(y, pred) {
  sqrt(mean((y - pred)^2))
}

#======================================================================
# OLS
#======================================================================

fit_ols <- lm(log_price ~ log_carat + cut + color + clarity + depth + table, 
              data = trainDF)
pred <- predict(fit_ols, testDF)
rmse(pred, test$y) # 0.1455683% on hold-out data

=================================================================================
Penalized regression
=================================================================================

# Tune elastic net parameters on validation data
set.seed(345)
for (a in seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)) {
  print(a)
  fit_glmnet <- cv.glmnet(x = train$X,
                          y = train$y,
                          family = "gaussian",
                          alpha = a,
                          nfolds = 5,
                          type.measure = "mse")
  cat("cvm: ", min(fit_glmnet$cvm))
  cat("lambda: ", fit_glmnet$lambda.min, "\n")
}

# Optimal values seem to be alpha 0.9, lambda = 0.002829157 
set.seed(399)
fit_glmnet <- glmnet(x = train$X, 
                     y = train$y, 
                     family = "gaussian", 
                     alpha = 0.9, 
                     lambda = 0.002829157)
pred <- predict(fit_glmnet, test$X, type = "response") 
rmse(test$y, pred) # 0.1456532 (slightly worse than OLS)


#======================================================================
# Untuned random forest with ranger
#======================================================================

fit_ranger <- ranger(log_price ~ log_carat + cut + color + clarity + depth + table, 
                     data = trainDF, 
                     always.split.variables = "log_carat", seed = 837363) 

rmse(test$y, predict(fit_ranger, testDF)$predictions) # 0.106 (much better than OLS)

#======================================================================
# Gradient boosting with XGBoost (slightly tuned by cross-validation)
#======================================================================

dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(train$X, label = train$y)
dtest <- xgb.DMatrix(test$X, label = test$y)
watchlist <- list(train = dtrain, test = dtest)

param <- list(max_depth = 8, 
              learning_rate = 0.01, 
              nthread = 7, 
              lambda = 0.2, 
              objective = "reg:linear", 
              eval_metric = "rmse", 
              subsample = 0.7)

system.time(fit_xgb <- xgb.train(param, 
                                 dtrain, 
                                 watchlist = watchlist, 
                                 nrounds = 850, 
                                 early_stopping_rounds = 5,
                                 verbose = 0))
rmse(test$y, predict(fit_xgb, test$X)) # 0.094 (beats all)
```

Comment: I see what you mean, thank you for the answer. 
For your information, for the next step, I will generate more derived attributes from original attributes try to make perdition more acculturate(With several feature selection methods).